# How to add transition to dropdown menu from W3

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu with transition based on the example from W3.  I have it working as a dropdown menu, but can't seem to add the transition.  I want the dropdown to ease in.

I have tried adding `transition: all 0.3s;` to the `.dropdown-content` class. I've also researched many other dropdown examples, but none have led to the answer.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.02);
  color: gray !important;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.02);
  color: gray;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 3em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3.5%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    clear: right;
    margin-top: 3em;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  }
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
  }
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #d51045;
    border-top: 2px solid #d51045;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
  .topnav {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    padding-top: 1em;
  }
  .topnav .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .topnav .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .topnav .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .dropdown-content a {
    float: none !important;
    text-align: center !important;
  }
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
}

.topnav a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444444;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444444;
  transition: color .2s ease-in;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  /*box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);*/
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: auto;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #d51045;
  border-top: 2px solid #d51045;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: right;
  padding: 20px 23px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body.home .site-header .container {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

img.nav-img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/220px-SNice.svg.png" height="22" class="nav-img">Calendar</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/220px-SNice.svg.png" height="22" class="nav-img">About 
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
             </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Musicians</a>
      <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/220px-SNice.svg.png" height="22" class="nav-img">Tickets 
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Series Subscriptions</a>
      <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/220px-SNice.svg.png" height="22" class="nav-img">Community
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Learning Programs</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/220px-SNice.svg.png" height="22" class="nav-img">Visit
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Seating Charts</a>
      <a href="#">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/220px-SNice.svg.png" height="22" class="nav-img">Give
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Ways to Give</a>
      <a href="#">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="active"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/220px-SNice.svg.png" height="22" class="nav-img">Shop</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

I expect the dropdown to have a smooth transition, similar to the laphil.org menu.

Comment: Are you using Javascript to display the .dropdown-content?

Comment: I've removed the [tag:w3c] because the W3 framework is by the awful W3Schools and not the W3C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the CSS display property. You want to animate dropdown appearance but you can't do it with display. Instead I suggest you to use visibility and opacity.

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  /*display: flex;*/
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```